# error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [9]' to 'LPCSTR'

Tags: c++, c, directx

When I add the following to my code.

```
// Define the input layout
D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
{
    { L"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },  
};
UINT numElements = sizeof(layout)/sizeof(layout[0]);
```

I get the following error

```
1>c:\users\numerical25\desktop\intro todirectx\msdntutorials\tutorial0\tutorial\tutorial\main.cpp(43) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [9]' to 'LPCSTR'
```

The error points straight to that line of code. if i remove the code, everything compiles correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that first element of D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC needs a `const char *`, not a `const wchar_t *`. Just remove the `L` before the string.

Comment: wow, I am getting this information from the directX docs. Not too accurate.